# npm i chai --save-dev issue

Tags: npm, mocha.js, chai

I'm using mocha to unit test for javascript
I'm using chai to manage assertion
After typing `npm i chai --save-dev` I obtain this error :

```
C:\Users\ABDELHAK>npm i chai --save-dev
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "chai" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v0.10.18
npm ERR! npm  v2.12.1
npm ERR! file C:\Users\ABDELHAK\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\chai\3.5.0\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '\u0000' at 1:1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\ABDELHAK\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\chai\3.5.0\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ABDELHAK\npm-debug.log
```

Note that mocha command works fine.

Comment: Did you do what the error message suggests?

Comment: sorry i am new with npm and i cant undrestand this error message ?? shall I update node version ?

Comment: This issue is resolved i taiping npm and then >npm i chai --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

Hmm looks like an empty package.json file in your npm cache. Maybe cleaning it will help you

```
$ npm cache clean once
```

Answer (score 0):

1. first delete registry using: npm config delete registry
2. clear cache: npm cache clear --force
3. then run your command: npm i chai --save-dev

hope it helps.